# How to organize multithreadings work with queue?

Tags: java, multithreading, find, queue, synchronized

I'm begginer and keep yourself in hends.

I need to do organize multithreadings find in files:

User input where find(path) and what find(word);

- First thread finds `.txt` files in folder and add result to queue;
- When queue has some file => Second thread start find in this file
  what need to find(word).
- If was finded success would show path this
  file + how offen times this word meets in file.

Qestions:

- Can we use ArrayList (or exist any alternatives) for queue which works with few threads?
- How to do if queue is empty, Second thread don't start but waits when First finded need file?
- Need we use synchronized for this task and inherited `MultiThreadingSearch`(or better to use composition)?

Code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class ArrayListOfFiles {
    private Node first, last;

    private class Node {
        String item;
        Node next;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return first == null;
    }

    public synchronized void enqueue(String item) {
        Node oldlast = last;
        last = new Node();
        last.item = item;
        last.next = null;
        if (isEmpty())
            first = last;
        else
            oldlast.next = last;
    }

    public synchronized String dequeue() {
        String item = first.item;
        first = first.next;
        if (isEmpty())
            last = null;
        return item;
    }
}

class FolderScan extends MultiThreadingSearch implements Runnable {

    FolderScan(String path, String whatFind) {
        super(path, whatFind);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        findFiles(path);
    }

    ArrayListOfFiles findFiles(String path) {
        File root = new File(path);
        File[] list = root.listFiles();
        for (File titleName : list) {
            if (titleName.isDirectory()) {
                findFiles(titleName.getAbsolutePath());
            } else {
                if (titleName.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith((".txt"))) {
                    textFiles.enqueue(titleName.getName());
                }
            }
        }

        return textFiles;
    }

}

class FileScan extends MultiThreadingSearch implements Runnable {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner((Readable) textFiles);
    Set<String> words = new HashSet<String>();
    int matches = 0;

    FileScan(String file, String whatFind) {
        super(file, whatFind);
        Thread wordFind = new Thread();
        wordFind.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String word = scanner.next();
            words.add(word);
        }

        if (words.contains(this.whatFind)) {
            System.out.println("File:" + this.path);
            matches++;
        }

        System.out.println(matches);
    }

}

public class MultiThreadingSearch {
    String path;
    String whatFind;

    ArrayListOfFiles textFiles;

    MultiThreadingSearch(String path, String whatFind) {
        this.path = path;
        this.whatFind = whatFind;
        this.textFiles = new ArrayListOfFiles();

        Thread pathFind = new Thread(new FolderScan(path, whatFind));
//      pathFind.start();

        if (!textFiles.isEmpty()) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            FileScan fileScan = new FileScan(textFiles.dequeue(), whatFind);
        }

    }

    // ask user about input
    public static void askUserPathAndWord() {

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String path;
        String whatFind;
        try {
            System.out.println("Please, enter a Path and Word"
                    + "(which you want to find):");
            System.out.println("Please enter a Path:");
            path = bufferedReader.readLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter a Word:");
            whatFind = bufferedReader.readLine();

            if (path != null && whatFind != null) {
                new MultiThreadingSearch(path, whatFind);
                System.out.println("Thank you!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("You did not enter anything");
            }

        } catch (IOException | RuntimeException e) {
            System.out.println("Wrong input!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        askUserPathAndWord();
    }
}
```

I got `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError` from this code.
How able to solve this task?

Thanks,
Nazar.

Comment: Where (on what line) did the Exception occur?

Comment: I suspect the exception occurred on some line not included in the code you posted. I cannot see anything here which would cause a StackOverflowError

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at task.MultiThreadingSearch.<init>(MultiThreadingSearch.java:101)
 at task.FolderScan.<init>(MultiThreadingSearch.java:41)` - I didn't expect this turn

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) it does exactly what you need. Thread can block until some other thread add new item to queue.
As to how decompose you system. I'd do following:

- Create class for searching txt files in path. It implements `Runnable`. You pass `path` and `queue` to it. And it searches path for txt files and adds them to the queu.
- Create class for searching file content. It implements `Runnable`. You pass `whatFind` and `queue` to it and it takes new file from queue and checks it's content.

Something like:

```
BlockingQueue<File> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<File>();
String path = ...;
String whatFind = ...;
FolderScan folderScan = new FolderScan(path, queue);
FileScan fileScan = new FileScan(whatFind, queue);

Executor executor = Executors.newCachecThreadPool();
executor.execute(folderScan);
executor.execute(fileScan);
```

If you want `FileScan` to wait until `FolderScan` adds something to the queue you can use [take](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#take%28%29) method:

```
BlockingQueue<File> queue;
File toProcess = queue.take(); // this line blocks current thread (FileScan) until someone adds new item to the queue.
```

Comment: `How to do if queue is empty, Second thread don't start but waits when First finded need file?` - general I don't know how this should do...

Comment: @Nikita Beloglazov Thanks!

Comment: You can traverse the directory tree, putting each folder inside the current directory on a folder task queue for a ThreadPool, using the execute method. Then each folder task may result in a number of txt files. Put these on a file task queue for another ThreadPool. So, folder scan and file scan run in parallel. Since the ThreadPools (like in the sample) use blocking queues for tasks, you never have to worry about starting and pausing threads. Look at the new file io in Java7, should give some speedup over the old file API. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html

Comment: @Nikita Beloglazov - I try to decompose my system. And add your logic to `askUserPathAndWord()`. After this some trouble - [new BlockingQueue](http://pastebin.com/CWGK5Rpb). And really don't understant where we can use `File toProcess = queue.take();`

Comment: @nazar_art `FileScan` should do following: take file from queue, scan it, take file from queue, scan it, etc. Here is an example how you can implement it: http://pastebin.com/JwZNV6N0

Comment: @Nikita I did this, add as answer lower. Only don't know how [to check MIME type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980320/java-how-to-check-mime-type-in-files)?

Answer (score 0):

After changes:

```
package task;

import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class FolderScan implements Runnable {

    private String path;
    private BlockingQueue<File> queue;
    private CountDownLatch latch;
    private File endOfWorkFile;

    FolderScan(String path, BlockingQueue<File> queue, CountDownLatch latch,
            File endOfWorkFile) {
        this.path = path;
        this.queue = queue;
        this.latch = latch;
        this.endOfWorkFile = endOfWorkFile;
    }

    public FolderScan() {  }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        findFiles(path);
        queue.add(endOfWorkFile);
        latch.countDown();
    }

    private void findFiles(String path) {

        try {
            File root = new File(path);
            File[] list = root.listFiles();
            for (File currentFile : list) {
                if (currentFile.isDirectory()) {
                    findFiles(currentFile.getAbsolutePath());
                } else {
                    if (currentFile.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith((".txt"))) {
                            queue.put(currentFile);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

public class FileScan implements Runnable {

    private String whatFind;
    private BlockingQueue<File> queue;
    private CountDownLatch latch;
    private File endOfWorkFile;

    public FileScan(String whatFind, BlockingQueue<File> queue,
            CountDownLatch latch, File endOfWorkFile) {
        this.whatFind = whatFind;
        this.queue = queue;
        this.latch = latch;
        this.endOfWorkFile = endOfWorkFile;
    }

    public FileScan() {     }

    Set<String> words = new HashSet<String>();
    int matches = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (true) {
            try {
                File file;
                file = queue.take();

                if (file == endOfWorkFile) {
                    break;
                }

                scan(file);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        latch.countDown();
    }

    private void scan(File file) {
        Scanner scanner = null;
        try {
            scanner = new Scanner(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("FileNotFoundException.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String word = scanner.next();
            words.add(word);
        }

        if (words.contains(this.whatFind)) {
            matches++;
        }

        String myStr = String.format("File: %s and the number of matches "
                + "is = %d", file.getAbsolutePath(), matches);
        System.out.println(myStr);

        matches = 0;
    }

    // ask user about input
    public void askUserPathAndWord() {

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String path;
        String whatFind;
        BlockingQueue<File> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<File>();

        try {
            System.out.println("Please, enter a Path and Word"
                    + "(which you want to find):");
            System.out.println("Please enter a Path:");
            path = bufferedReader.readLine();
            System.out.println("Please enter a Word:");
            whatFind = bufferedReader.readLine();

            if (path != null && whatFind != null) {

                File endOfWorkFile = new File("GameOver.tmp");
                CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(2);

                FolderScan folderScan = new FolderScan(path, queue, latch,
                        endOfWorkFile);
                FileScan fileScan = new FileScan(whatFind, queue, latch,
                        endOfWorkFile);

                Executor executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
                executor.execute(folderScan);
                executor.execute(fileScan);

                latch.await();
                System.out.println("Thank you!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("You did not enter anything");
            }

        } catch (IOException | RuntimeException e) {
            System.out.println("Wrong input!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FileScan().askUserPathAndWord();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This may not sound too constructive, but you can either fix that code or read something like [this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/index.html) first and then throw away your code.
Stackoverflow usually results from a recursion running deeper than expected. Make sure there is some condition in you recursive method that stops recursion.

Comment: OK since this is getting voted either direction: What I mean is, usually, when one knows the abstractions provided by java.util.concurrent and maybe has seen some sample code, one would design his own code accordingly to take advantage of the building blocks in the JDK. And this, of course entails throwing away own code that tried to reinvent the wheel.